# loading a text file for quick access C# windows form app

Tags: c#, sql, text

I couldn't find an answer to this on the other stackoverflow is I'll ask it here.  I have a text file with roughly 100000 rows.  I have been doing multiple queries on it such as this

```
string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";
string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
string sql = @"SELECT Count(*) as NumberofRecords FROM [" + fileName + "]";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
       @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
       ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

And it is doing multiple versions of this.  Is there any way to load the textfile so that I can run things like this faster?  Is there a better way?  Currently it is taking too long.

Comment: Are you doing enough queries to justify optimizing this?  If so, you could just suck the whole thing into a `DataTable` or an in memory database once and run queries against that.

Comment: So, can you post a more complicated sample together with the time it needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do?

From your sample it looks like the only thing you're trying to do is to get the number of records in the file.

You might be safe to instead just count the number of lines (-1 line for the header) iff* you don't have content that spans multiple lines.

***** *if, and only if*

**EDIT:**

So counting the number of lines is not an option since you're doing more complicated stuff.

I just generated a sample file with 100k records (7.7 MB in size) which got processed in 0.43 seconds. Doing a `count(*) .. group by Name` took 0.58 seconds.

What are your numbers and why do you think it's taking too long? Where does the file lie? Is it perhaps a network/slow drive issue?

Comment: There are other things that are a bit more complicated, like counting the combinations of first and last names, I just posted the simplest possible one.

Answer (score 0):

Load the file into memory using a stream, See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304430). Once it's in memory, run your queries etc.

Comment: Good option for small file, but I think it is not good option for loading such huge file (100000 rows) into memory.

Comment: well each row will be maybe two dozen bytes * 100000 so you are in the mega bytes order. You probably have a few gigabytes of memory, so you really have nothing to worry about

Comment: How do you want to convince OleDbConnection to work with your memory stream?

Comment: this would negate the need for such activites as the file could be accessed directly

Comment: @ldgorman: so tell me how to "run queries" on an in-memory blob.

Comment: @VVS You would need to add the data to a collection and then you could use LINQ or write your own routines

Comment: @ldgorman: So.. to add the data to a collection you would have to parse it, right? Did you know parsing a CSV is *really hard*? (worth reading: http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp) You're replacing one problem with a huge number of bigger problems.

Comment: No it really isn't, and he doesn't specify what data he is accessing. It may need only the simplest parsing, like whole words, where the space delimiter could be used for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the the following example:

```
string filename = @"C:\BigTextFile.txt";  
StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(filename);

// Process line by line.  
string line = "";  
do  
{  
line = sr.ReadLine();  
}  
while(sr.Peek() != -1);  

// Load all at once and process.  
string alltext = sr.ReadToEnd();  

sr.Close();
```

Comment: so, you have a long string, what next

Comment: @Jodrell: You only have the last line and alltext should be empty :)

Comment: Why the vote down? The code showed two approaches namely reading line by line or all at once.